# Count of Concurrent Entries with Start and Stop Times

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a Django Model that looks something like this:

```
def UserHistory(models.Model):
    userName = models.CharField(255)
    startTime = models.DateTimeField()
    stopTime = models.DateTimeField()
```

What I want is a count of concurrent entries, For example if my records look like this:

```
ID    User    Start    Stop
---------------------------
1      A      01:00    05:00
2      B      02:00    07:00
3      C      03:00    04:00
4      A      06:00    08:00
```

I would like it to become:

```
Count    Start    Stop
----------------------
1        01:00    02:00
2        02:00    03:00
3        03:00    04:00
2        04:00    05:00
1        05:00    06:00
2        06:00    07:00
1        07:00    08:00
```

Do you know how I can achieve this with Django?  I've come close to this in SQL by creating a table of time then inner joining that table with the data and doing a count.  This is not exactly the same because the resolution is only as good as the time table that you make.

Thanks!